# How to postback on a google map popup

Tags: c#, google-maps, jquery-plugins

My app uses google maps with the google api. I display all of my pins on the map and when I click on a pin, I have set up the popup to display an html table with projects that are associated to each pin on the map. I use a StringBuilder to create this table and I response.write it to the InfoWindow.aspx page. My client now wants to be able to sort this table by column header but I can't seem to find a way to set up a postback on the google popup. I tried creating a gridview programmaticaly and adding it to a placeholder on the page but that doesn't work. I can't seem to drag a GridView on this page either...the popup will not display. 
Has anyone had to do this before or can point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Here's what I got so far:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("<head><link rel='stylesheet' href='http://tablesorter.com/docs/css/jq.css' type='text/css'media='print, projection, screen' /><link rel='stylesheet' href='http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/style.css' type='text/css' media='print, projection, screen' /> <script type='text/javascript' src='http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://tablesorter.com/docs/js/chili/chili-1.8b.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://tablesorter.com/docs/js/docs.js'></script>");

sb.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>"); 
sb.AppendLine(" $(document).ready(function () {");
            //// call the tablesorter plugin
            sb.AppendLine("    $('#Projects').tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0],[2,1]], widgets: ['zebra']});");
            // sort on the first column and third column, order asc
            sb.AppendLine("});");
            sb.AppendLine("});");

            sb.AppendLine("</script>");
            sb.AppendLine("</head>");



            sb.AppendLine("<br /><table id='Projects' class='tablesorter' cellspacing='0' >");
            sb.AppendLine("<thead>");
            sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
            sb.AppendLine("<th>");
            sb.AppendLine("File Number");
            sb.AppendLine("</th>");
            sb.AppendLine("<th>");
            sb.AppendLine("Ref. Number");
            sb.AppendLine("</th>");
            sb.AppendLine("<th>");
            sb.AppendLine("Project Name");
            sb.AppendLine("</th>");
            sb.AppendLine("<th>");
            sb.AppendLine("Department");
            sb.AppendLine("</th>");
            sb.AppendLine("<th>");
            sb.AppendLine("Budget");
            sb.AppendLine("</th></tr>");
            sb.AppendLine("</thead>");


            List<Project> oProjectSummaries = Projects.GetActive();
            sb.AppendLine("<tbody>");
            foreach (ProjectSummary oProjectSummary in oProjectSummaries)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
                sb.AppendLine("<td nowrap>");


                var projectId = oProjectSummary.ProjectNumber.Substring(2); //string awaw "P-"
                projectId = projectId.TrimStart('0');
                sb.AppendLine("<a href='../ProjectProfile.aspx?id=" + projectId + "' target='_blank'>" + oProjectSummary.ProjectNumber + "</a>");
                }

                sb.AppendLine("</td>");
                sb.AppendLine("<td>");
                sb.AppendLine(oProjectSummary.InternalReferenceNumber);
                sb.AppendLine("</td>");
                sb.AppendLine("<td>");
                sb.AppendLine(oProjectSummary.ProjectName);
                sb.AppendLine("</td>");
                sb.AppendLine("<td>");
                sb.AppendLine(oProjectSummary.AbbreviationText);
                sb.AppendLine("</td>");
                sb.AppendLine("<td nowrap align='right' style='padding-right:15px;'>");
                sb.AppendLine(oProjectSummary.FormattedContribution);
                sb.AppendLine("</td>");
                sb.AppendLine("</tr>");

            }

            sb.AppendLine("</tbody>");
            sb.AppendLine("</table>");

            Response.Write(sb);
```

Comment: can you show some code?
Your page InfoWindow.aspx is already being showed in the marker infowindow?

Comment: I've added some code for the jquery tablesorter plugin. I figured this would be the only way to achieve this. This doesn't work as well. Table gets formatted as per the css files but Javascript is not executing. The StringBuilder gets written out to InfoWindow.aspx.

Comment: How you put all this together in the google.maps Infowindow?

Comment: There is also a GoogleMap.js file which is a javascript  file that helps with pin placement on the map as well as some other options but I don't think that file is relevant. It only asks for the url of my page and I set it to InfoWindow.aspx...my page takes care of the rest. The codebehind for the InfoWindow.aspx is where I response.write the StringBuilder above.